# How Google Anlytics gathers information about search engines and keywords?

Tags: google-analytics

How Google Analytics gathers information  about search engines and keywords? I assume that Referer header is used to identify search engines. But how Google Analytics gets info about keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA takes it from the HTTP referrer.
Run

```
javascript:alert(document.referrer)
```

On your console and see the referrer info. This is what I get from bing. Note my original search query "http+referrer":

[image]

However, now that Google employs secure search (that is, over https) the search terms of users coming from Google's organic search results do not appear in the HTTP referrer anymore. Now you will see "(not provided)" on most organic search term GA reports instead.